# Proper form of "user request"

Tags: grammatical-number, articles, internet, saxon-genitive

The context is an Internet platform to which http requests are sent. In a sentence like this:

```
The system behaves differently when users' requests increase.
```

what is the correct usage of `user request` terminology? 
I have the following doubts:

- I think the article is not needed: is it? (`when users' requests` vs `when the users' requests`)
- Is saxon genitive mandatory, optional or must it not be used at all? I am more comfortable with `user request` expression but often I found the `user's request` expression.
- plural: are `user requests` and `users requests` both valid? If so are they interchangeable or are there some differences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  The definite article is not necessary in these kinds of contexts. In documentation of this sort, you'll see both "a user makes a request" and "the user makes a request," since you're speaking of a hypothetical user. Of course, if you defined a narrower subset of users and were speaking about them, you'd need the direct article: "Users can log in and after they've done so, the users can view their account."

2) It's optional, and to my ear, sounds worse. I prefer "user requests," which puts the focus a little more on the request than on the user (and the system performs differently because of the requests, not because of the users). It's a subtle distinction, though.

3) "Users requests" is not a form that you would ordinarily see, but it's grammatically valid.  *Users requests* would be the plural of *users request*. A *users request* would be a single request that is made by a group of users (for instance, a group of users vote on which request they want to make), or more likely, it might be a request **for** multiple users - i.e. not a request made by the users, but a request made by someone who wanted users.

Remember that attributive nouns, like the adjectives they resemble, or function as, are not pluralized, unlike some other languages.

*One user request* => *two user requests* **NOT** *two users requests*
*One mouse trap* => *two mouse traps* **NOT** *two mice traps*

Also note that some attributive nouns are always plural.

*One sales manager* => *two sales managers*
*One singles bar* => *two singles bars*

What determines whether an attribute noun should be plural or singular?  Unfortunately, it seems there's no clear answer.  This article is insightful: "[Why isn’t it a gumsballs machine?](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/compound-nouns)"

Comment: Sorry I meant `user requests` vs `users request`

Comment: @FrancescoBoi I've edited my answer to reflect your changes.